# Adding description to AutoMapped fields in GraphQL.EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, graphql

I am using this library to map my Entity objects as Graphs:

https://github.com/SimonCropp/GraphQL.EntityFramework

I know if I manually create a field I can add a description, like so:

```
        AddNavigationField(
            name: "mainAddress",
            description: "Main Address",
            resolve: x => x.Source.MainAddress);
```

Is there a way to add descriptions to fields that were created using AutoMap()?  Preference would be through annotations on the Entity object's properties, but I'd be interested in any method of doing this.  Main reason is to add a pretty name to each field for display on a web interface, rather than displaying the camel cased name, so if there's a better way than using description I'd also be interested in that.